# How to: Schedule a Job (Stored Procedure / Trigger)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to Schedule a Stored Procedure / Trigger in Microsoft SQL server ?

Comment: use the wizard....You can't schedule triggers (directly)

Comment: @Mitch, what exactly do you consider high-quality?  These kinds of questions are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Robert: it's not a programming question.

Comment: Did I miss something? Are non-programming questions now acceptable?

Comment: Aside from that, I consider it low-quality because a quick internet search would answer it more than adequately

Comment: @Mitch: Well, I can't imagine anyone but a programmer or DBA needing to know the answer to this question.

Comment: Many Questions that DBAs need to know, are not considered relevant here.

Comment: @Mitch: This is what I consider a low quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976438/report-viewer-doesnot-show-report-that-create-with-reporting-service

Comment: I'll toss in my 2 cents here and say that although it's not *directly* related to programming, it's definitely "adjacent" to the problem space.  A web developer is often asked about scheduled notifications.  Just like DNS and SMTP, it's good to know, and it quickly becomes required learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it up as a job under the SQL Server Agent from the Management console.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Management Studio > SQL Server Agent > Jobs > New > Enter a name and owner (usually sa) > Steps > New... > Choose your DB and type in your s.p. name.

From there, choose your schedule.