# Report Viewer Doesn't Show report created with Sql Server Reporting Services

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

I created some reports in Sql Server Reporting Services, and deployed them in my local report server.  When I type URL :`http://MyreportServer/ReportServer` in my browser I can see my deployed reports, and when clicks on reports links they will show correctly.

In my web page I have a report viewer and set report server and report location for it to one of the deployed reports.  When I run the project it does not show any thing and the report viewer seems to be disabled.

How I can solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: Did you use report builder wizard?

Comment: No.I just deploy reports using Deploy item in reporting service project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found stupid problem.
I Have a p tag that not closed in my page.and It cause this problem.